# Visual Studio Code, Entity Framework Core - dotnet ef migrations not recognized

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

The problem is in starting migrations to .NET 6 itself.

I'm using .NET 6 and I was making a mistake trying to run migrations with Add Migrations, and I came across a solution that works for many which is:

```
dotnet ef migrations
```

When I tried to start the migrations, I got an error:

[image]

Otherwise I use linux ubuntu 22.04.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?

Comment: Error messages are text and should be included as such in your question. That error looks like a dependency problem related to how dotnet was installed.

Comment: "Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this?" The error seems to give you a suggestion on how to solve this. Did you try it? What happened?